# Why this same code produce two different fp results on different Machines?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

const double ln2per12 = log(2.0) / 12.0;

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);
    double target = 9.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125;
    double unnormalizatedValue = 9.79999999999063220457173883914947509765625;
    double ln2per12edValue = unnormalizatedValue * ln2per12;
    double errorLn2per12 = fabs(target - ln2per12edValue / ln2per12);
    std::cout << unnormalizatedValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << ln2per12 << std::endl;
    std::cout << errorLn2per12 << " <<<<< its different" << std::endl;
}
```

If I try on my machine (`MSVC`), or [here](http://cpp.sh/9w5s2) (`GCC`):

```
errorLn2per12 = 9.3702823278363212011754512786865234375e-12
```

Instead, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b19830a018d4cb6)  (`GCC`):

```
errorLn2per12 = 9.368505970996920950710773468017578125e-12
```

which is different. Its due to [Machine Epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)? Or Compiler precision flags? Or a different `IEEE` evaluation?

What's the cause here for this drift? The problem seems in `fabs()` function (since the other values seems the same).

Comment: All sorts of things could be going on.  Some machines have more precision then `double` actually uses and you'll get less compound error with the results saying in those extended registers then you would if each operation gets truncated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `-Ofast` turns on `-ffast-math`. Which _[...can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions_](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: "Or Compiler precision flags?" - Impossible to answer when you don't tell us *what flags* you pass to your compiler. But, yes, some flags, like `-Ofast` for GCC allows the compiler to break the rules and *can* lead to weird results (don't use it) - the Microsoft compiler has similar dangerous flags.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: please NO! This is not a duplicate of that question! Its specific per platform. Please read carefully

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia IEEE754 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) , double precision values have 15.95 decimal digits. Anything beyond that will lose precision.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: you have links, you can check the flags

Comment: not a duplicate at all of that question

Comment: Obviously not a dup

Comment: first off I think the expectation is broken of the results.  not the code/compiler itself.  but start by examining the disassembly to see that both/all start with the same conversion to binary of those constants...

Comment: And yes, [replacing `-Ofast` by `-O2` on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c39d17e908153635) turns the 9.368... into the 9.370...

Comment: @markzzz Links can go stale, making the question worthless if those links contained crucial information. Try to make the question self-contained.

Comment: @markzzz The flags should be *in* the question, not behind external links. As far as I'm concerned, if I have to follow a link, it doesn't exist as part of the question.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247084/5470596

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even without `-Ofast`, the C++ standard does not require implementations to be exact with `log` (or `sin`, or `exp`, etc.), only that they be within a few ulp (i.e. there may be some inaccuracies in the last binary places). This allows faster hardware (or software) approximations, which each platform/compiler may do differently.

(*The only floating point math function that you will always get perfect results from on all platforms is `sqrt`.*)

More annoyingly, you may even get different results between compilation (the compiler may use some internal library to be as precise as `float`/`double` allows for constant expressions) and runtime (e.g. hardware-supported approximations).

If you want `log` to give the exact same result across platforms and compilers, you will have to implement it yourself using only `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `sqrt` (or find a library with this guarantee). And avoid a whole host of pitfalls along the way.

If you need floating point determinism in general, I strongly recommend reading this article to understand how big of a problem you have ahead of you: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: There's also some obscure flag to disallow the compiler to perform floating point operation on the hardware natural float size (generally 80 bits). I've read something somewhere.

Comment: This is also worth a read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @YSC See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: the real "deal" is that if I remove the ln2per12 as const, the results are the same. It seems that `const` do somethings different... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d246fa05447efe19

Comment: @markzzz See the paragraph about differences between compilation and run time. (Also see the linked article under "Transcendentals".) With `const`, the compiler can constant-fold the expression and replace it with a precise value at compile-time. Without, it has to initialize it at runtime, which may use a completely different method for calculating `log`.

Comment: @ Max Langhof: if that's true, I would expect to see different outputs for that value when I `cout` it. Instead, its the same. Try this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c113f402cf81e667 . It hasn't `log` at all, `b` is printed the same (with/without `const`), but `c / b` lead to different results with/without set `const` on `b`

Comment: @markzzz Looking at the assembly [with](https://godbolt.org/z/4u-cgr) and [without const](https://godbolt.org/z/SqfmeD), the compiler constant-folds everything in both cases, no calculation happens at runtime. The difference is surprising, I agree, but fully within the range of conceivable compiler optimizations. For the record, if you use `-O3` instead, you get the same result in both cases. If you want to know where precisely the difference comes from you'll have to dig through `gcc` optimization internals, but you have to live with it regardless.

Comment: Its not clear at all why this is happens. Since its not related with Log anymore, I think I would delete this question and open a "more one" with a precise target. Can you remove my question? Since you have replied, I can't...

Comment: What's the point of removing the question? Just ask a new one if you want to, but I don't think you'll get a good answer to "why does `gcc` optimize this in different ways". If you're lucky someone will guide you through the optimization sources, but what would you gain from it?

Comment: Let see what's happening!