# Why does setting a const variable (which will be stored with the same value) lead to a different result once divided?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, constants

Pretty [basic](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fe521a855c0a8ec) code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout.precision(100);

    double a            = 9.79999999999063220457173883914947509765625;
    double b            = 0.057762265046662104872599030613855575211346149444580078125;
    const double bConst = 0.057762265046662104872599030613855575211346149444580078125;
    double c            = a * b;

    std::cout << "        a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "        b: " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "   bConst: " << bConst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "        c: " << c << std::endl << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "      c/b: " << c / b << std::endl;   
    std::cout << " c/bConst: " << c / bConst << std::endl;  
}
```

Which outputs:

```
        a: 9.79999999999063220457173883914947509765625
        b: 0.057762265046662104872599030613855575211346149444580078125
   bConst: 0.057762265046662104872599030613855575211346149444580078125
        c: 0.5660701974567474703547986791818402707576751708984375

      c/b: 9.7999999999906304282148994388990104198455810546875
 c/bConst: 9.79999999999063220457173883914947509765625
```

As you can see, `b` and `bConst` seem to be treated using the same value - i.e. it prints for both the same `0.057762265046662104872599030613855575211346149444580078125` value. 
So I guess they are "stored" both the same. The only difference is that `b` is not `const`.

Then, I do the same `c / b` operation twice: one time using `b`, another time using `bConst`.

As you can see, it leads to two different results. And this makes me wonder.

Can you explain technically why this happens?

Comment: Here (mingw-w64 with g++ 8.1) both results are the same when optimized with -O2 and I get your result with -Ofast.

Comment: I thought you got a grasp of the perverse effects of `-Ofast`on floatting operation determinism in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54694274/5470596

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "issue" is due to the `-freciprocal-math` switch (implied by `-Ofast`):

> Allow the reciprocal of a value to be used instead of dividing by the value if this enables optimizations. For example `x / y` can be replaced with `x * (1/y)`, which is useful if `(1/y)` is subject to common subexpression elimination. Note that this loses precision and increases the number of flops operating on the value.

The compiler can calculate `d = 1/bConst` at compile time and change from:

```
c/bConst
```

to

```
c * d
```

but multiplication and division are different instructions with different performance and precision.

See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba9770ec39ec5ac2

Comment: Thank you for that explanation... interesting!

Comment: Uhm... not sure that's the behaviour: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79e5a3501af9a217 . Using `c * 1 / b` = `c / b)` (giving `b` = `bConst`). Instead, `c * 1 / bConst` give the same as `c / bConst`... so it should be somethings different.

Comment: Uhm... wait! If I did `c * (1 / b)` (instead of `c * 1 / b`) works as you said.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `-Ofast` in your link, which enables all `-O3` optimizations and includes both `-ffast-math`, which in turns includes `-funsafe-math-optimizations`.

From what I could glean, with optimizations enabled, `-funsafe-math-optimizations` allows the compiler to reduce the precision of some computations. This seems to be what happens in the `c/bConst` case.

Comment: The anwer is correct. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: What do you mean with "leads to a different result depending on the const-ness"? Shouldn't I get the same results starting with the same quotient and dividend?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I'm looking into it.

Comment: @markzzz Unsafe optimizations tend to not care about this kind of logic.