# Very odd code under certain conditions including optimizations

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I have this snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     

void optimization_headache()    
{    
    int t = 11;    
    int l[1047] = {0};    
    int u_lu[23] = {0};    

    int u = 0;    

    l[0] = 0;    
    l[1] = 0;    

    do {    
        u++;    
        //printf("Incrementing u, now u is %d\n", u);     
        u_lu[u + 1] = u - l[u + 1];    
    } while ((u < t * 2) && (l[u + 1] <= t));    

    printf("u = %d, l[u] = %d, t = %d, u_lu[u] = %d\n", u, l[u], t, u_lu[u]);    
}    

int main()    
{    
    optimization_headache();    

    return 0;    
}
```

Upon compiling with optimizations off (`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -O0 main.c`), the code compiles, and I get the following output:

`u = 22, l[u] = 0, t = 11, u_lu[u] = 21`

When I compile with full optimizations (`$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 main.c`), the program hangs, and top indicates it's using 100% of my CPU. It must be running forever in the do while loop.

I can get the code to compile with full optimizations and run correctly by changing one or all of the following:

1) If I comment out `l[0] = 0; l[1] = 0;`.

2) If I make `u` a `volatile int` instead.

3) If I uncomment the `printf` inside the do while loop.

So obviously, I don't understand what the optimizations are doing, and why it changes the behavior of my program.  I could just choose one of the above solutions to get it to run, but I really really want to know what's going on here.  It's so weird to me.

(The C++ tag might not be appropriate, but I see the same behavior using g++ as well)

Comment: The behavior goes away with `-fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations` which means you likely have undefined behavior see [C++ compilation bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32506643/1708801) for a detailed explanation of what gcc is doing. Most likely an out of bounds access is happening.

Comment: Your code can write to `u_lu[23]`. (you loop while `u < 22` but `u` is incremented twice).

Comment: What version of gcc and what platform are you on?  Both compiled versions run just fine on my Mac.

Comment: it's a damned shame that no compilers have a -fflag-undefined-behaviour option...

Comment: Aside: `l[0] = 0; l[1] = 0;` is unnecessary since you already defined `int l[1047] = {0};`

Comment: @Wimmel OH MY GOODNESS. I spent so much time widdling this small example from a huge error correction library just to post it here, I didn't have brain cells left to look at the code well enough.  It was also the fact that commenting certain things out and in, and making u volatile threw me for a loop.  Post your comment as the answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: If minor changes affect the behaviour, you are probably indexing out of range.

Comment: By changing small things that didn't make sense should have been a red flag for undefined behavior in the first place :(

Comment: @WeatherVane I know! That's why this code snippet was twisting my brain.  It made no sense that by redefining the elements the code would work.  But like the comments already suggested, changing stuff that doesn't make sense should have pointed to undefined behavior, not optimization weirdness.

Comment: Behavior that changes with optimization level is a strong indication of undefined behavior.

Comment: @justynnuff that's why I ticked up your previous comment and the question too, you have morenuff between your ears!

Comment: @RichardHodges GCC and Clang do have such a flag. This particular bug will be caught by `-fsanitize=address`. For other (not memory  access related) UBs there is  `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Comment: @IlyaPopov thanks. This ought to be enabled by default!!

Comment: @RichardHodges, No, because they involve quite significant runtime overhead (like 2x memory and 3x time).

Comment: @RichardHodges See more detail in this CppCon 2014 talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2_80g0eOMc

Comment: @IlyaPopov thank you for the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this could happen if you invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/33499).

In your case, this is the relevant part:

```
int t = 11;    
int u_lu[23] = {0};    

do {    
    u++;    
    u_lu[u + 1] = u - l[u + 1];    
} while ((u < t * 2) /*...*/);
```

The loop runs while `u` is smaller then 22, so it can become 21. But inside the loop, you increment `u` twice and writing to `u_lu[23]`. This is one more then allocated.