# loop control is throwing undefined behavior

Tags: c

I have upgraded my GCC compiler from 4.1.2 to 4.8.3, When i compile my source code with 4.8.3 version i am facing below issue.

Error:
iteration 8u invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimizations]

```
{
uint index;
for ( index =0 ; index<BLOCK_SIZE; index++) 
ltoP->kdlllp= riv64[7-index]; 
}
```

Can any one please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Please fix you post's formatting. Prefix lines in a code block with 4 spaces.

Comment: Done.please check!

Comment: See this related [question in which a program steps outside array bounds and triggers gcc aggressive loop optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32506643/1708801) although in this example a cout obscures the warning and instead gcc turns it into an infinite loop whereas before it was finite.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour ...Sure.i Will check.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When `index` is 8; `riv64[7-index]` is `riv64[-1u]`, which is undefined. The `8u` in the message suggests the type of `index` is `unsigned int`, in which case `7-index` will evaluate to a very large value that is outside the array bounds. (`7-8u` will be evaluated as `7u-8u`, which is equivalent to `-1u`. Unsigned arithmetic wraps, so that produces a very large value, `UINT_MAX`.)

Comment: Eric,Thanks fro your reply.What should i need to do here to fix this?

Comment: @NaveenKumar: From the code you have shown, we can see `riv64[7-index]` is wrong. Without seeing more code, we cannot see why it is used or what the fix should be.

Comment: Hi Eric, As you mentioned above riv64 is array with index 8,  snippet.              

    void hdcp22UpdateConfigPseudoRandomNumberRiv( hdcp22PT hdcpP, guchar riv64[8],hdcp22T endianess)
/*!endpublic*/
    {    if ( endianess == P22_BIG_ENDIAN )
        memcpy(hdcpP->hdcp22ConfigP->pseudoRandomNumberRiv, riv64, 8);
    else {
        guint index;
        for ( index =0 ; index<AES_BLOCK_SIZE; index++) 
            hdcpP->hdcp22ConfigP->pseudoRandomNumberRiv[index] = riv64[7-index]; 
    }
}

Comment: @NaveenKumar: That code appears to be reversing `riv64` to adjust for endianness. If so, the loop index should be limited by the size of `riv64`, not `AES_BLOCK_SIZE`. But that is still too small a portion of the code to judge well, and programs should not be debugged by means of Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: I will check and confirm.